# Can Django do further process after AJAX response?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm working on a Django application processing AJAX requests. The code is like this:

```py
def handler(request):
    # save the data to the database
    return HttpResponse(# some json)
```

The problem is that I want to further process the data that the user has submitted, but after responding the user with the success information. So is there a way to make the response without using `return` ? Or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I have no idea how to return `HTTPResponse` without using `return`, but I thought of a trick. After you've received the response in your `js` or `jquery` code, make another `ajax` call to server and ask it to start its process on data, then handle this data process in a separate method not in the `handler`. You can also use `handler` with some considerations; I mean you can check if a particular key is in the `ajax` request or not and then decide either process data or response to `ajax`.

Comment: Thanks to Zeinab. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use Celery for this type of task: it's the standard for asynchronous processing.
You can learn more about it here:
[Django with celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Comment: Thx, but actually I'm deploying the app on a cloud, where only pure python code is supported. So is there a simpler way to do that (native python without external tools)?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but most python hosts provide celery support (openshift, gondor, etc)